# Encoding special chracters to Base64 in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, utf-8, base64, vba

I have XML text in an Excel sheet that I want to encode with Base64. I've found some code which actually does a good job. The only problem is that I cannot encode special characters like the German umlaut with VBA in Excel.
So does anybody know how to do this? I think it should be possible since the PHP base64 function can handle such characters too.

Comment: Where did you find the code/ what is the code? Please update your question to include this

Comment: Convert the XML text in UTF-8 or Unicode to binary data via `ADODB.Stream`, then convert that binary to Base64 via `MSXml2.DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base64 encoded string represents the initial string containing special characters in some charset, suitable for such special characters. So first of all you should choose which charset to use. Usually UTF-8 or UTF-16 will do. I guess the issue you encountered is cased by ASCII.

In the below example `TextBase64Encode` function allows to encode a text to Base64 and `TextBase64Decode` to decode it back to text:

```vb
Function TextBase64Encode(strText, strCharset)

    Dim arrBytes

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Open
        .Charset = strCharset
        .WriteText strText
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        arrBytes = .Read
        .Close
    End With

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("tmp")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .nodeTypedValue = arrBytes
        TextBase64Encode = Replace(Replace(.Text, vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")
    End With

End Function

Function TextBase64Decode(strBase64, strCharset)

    Dim arrBinary

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("tmp")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .Text = strBase64
        arrBinary = .nodeTypedValue
    End With

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write arrBinary
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Charset = strCharset
        TextBase64Decode = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With

End Function
```

To make it more clear I entered a sample, containing special characters like the German umlaut in the cell `A2`, charset `ASCII` in `B2` and formula `=TextBase64Encode($A$2;B2)` in `C2`. ASCII represented string encoded to Base64 appeared in cell `C2`:

[image: step1]

Entered formula `=TextBase64Decode(C2;B2)` in `D2` to decode Base64 back:

[image: step2]

Added more charsets, stretched formulas down and added header:

[image: step3]

Now you can see, that UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-7, Windows-1250, latin1 keeps initial sample umlauts, but ASCII spoils. For a list of the character set names that are known by a system, see the subkeys of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Charset` in the Windows Registry. Note that UTF-16 LE encoded string often includes the bytes 0xFF, 0xFE at the start, which are the Unicode byte order mark (BOM), and UTF-8 representation of the BOM are the bytes 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF at the start. BTW just replace `bin.base64` with `bin.hex` to work with heximal values instead of Base64.